# Vim 80 character line in specific files

Tags: vim, character-limit

I've recently started to use Vim. I set 80 character line in .vimrc, using follow command:

```
set colorcolumn=80
```

But this line is displayed not in all files. Look at screenshots below:

[image]
[image]

My .vimrc is [here](http://pastebin.com/viGsfkDT). Does anybody know, what problem is?

Comment: Put your .vimrc in something that doesn't require a login like www.pastebin.com or gist.github.com.

Comment: @robbrit I've updated link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the following lines scattered within your vimrc:

```
" higlight column right after max textwidth
set colorcolumn=+1

" Disable vertical line at max string length in NERDTree
autocmd FileType * setlocal colorcolumn=+1
autocmd FileType nerdtree setlocal colorcolumn=""

set colorcolumn=80
```

Also relevant is the fact that you have not apparently set `'textwidth'` to anything, so it should be at its default value of zero, and from the vim help on `'colorcolumn'`:

> When 'textwidth' is zero then the items with '-' and '+' are not used.

So, what I suspect is happening is that the autocommand with `*` as the wildcard is running and setting `colorcolumn=+1`, which is basically disabling it, since `'textwidth'` is zero.

Thus, you can solve the problem by either ensuring `'textwidth'` is set, or removing the autocommand. And, more generally, you should clean up your various settings of `'colorcolumn'` within your vimrc to not negate / interfere with one another.

Comment: Thank you very much! I've removed autocommands. and left one row with colorcolumn